# How to enable a single button in the CKEDITOR when its in readonly mode

Tags: php, javascript, ckeditor

I created a plugin for CKEDITOR which will open a popup dialog. And i want it to be enabled even when my CKEDITOR is in readOnly mode. Is there anyway i can do it?

Also i want to know is there any way to disable the Source button in the readOnly mode.

Whether the editor is disabled or enabled is determined dynamically and i want all the toolbars to be present but in the disabled mode, so i can't remove the source button from the toolbar.

I'm trying to find a way for last 3hours, and i can't get to it. And its urgent. :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey, is this issue still open? Did you manage to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This stupid horrible hack might help you :)

```
// Save command after loading editor.
var sourceCommand = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.ui._.items.Source.args[0].command;

// When disabling editor, unset command
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.ui._.items.Source.args[0].command = undefined;

// When enabling editor, reset command
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.ui._.items.Source.args[0].command = sourceCommand;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this once the editor is loaded and add/remove the tools you want and don't want

> var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'txtarea_name',
>   {
>           toolbar : 
>   [ ['NewPage'],
>   ['Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteWord'],
>   ['Undo','Redo','Bold','Italic','Underline','StrikeThrough'],
>   ['OrderedList','UnorderedList'],
>   ['NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent'],
>   ['JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock'],
>   ['Font','FontSize']]
>
> ```
>       }
> ```
>
> );

Comment: S.M.09, as i said i need the Source button in the non-readOnly version. And the user can enable or disable the editor. If i use the above config, then even when the editor is enabled the Source button won't be there. :(

Comment: @Anush add the button you want and remove the ones you dont want from the `toolbar ` array

Comment: i want `Source` button when its enabled. 

Ok consider this situation. There is a demo application for readonly in ckeditor http://nightly.ckeditor.com/7164/_samples/readonly.html . My situation is similar, i have a button to make the editor readonly and enable editing. I want the source button also to be disabled when the makereadonly button is clicked.